# Delete item from Cart -Spring MVC

Tags: java, spring-mvc

I am developing a small application using spring mvc where I need to have option to delete each item from cart (in case customer feels he donot need after adding to cart).
I have got a "delete" button below each item item.(The items added are in a list).My pupose is when I click delete button against a particular item only that item should be removed from the cart.

I have written some code but it is remove lastest added items from cart and not required one.

I know my mistake but not able to proceed further.Here is what I implemented.
This is jsp :

```
            <c:forEach items="${cart}" var="nextMovie">
        <li>
            <h2>${nextMovie.title}</h2>
                    </li>
        <h2>Price</h2>
        <h2>${nextMovie.price}</h2>

        <c:set var="totalPrice" value="${0}" />
       <c:forEach var="nextMovie" items="${cart}">
       <c:set var="totalPrice" value="${totalPrice + nextMovie.price}"/>
        </c:forEach>
            <form method='post' action='<c:url value="removeFromCart.do"/>'>
                    <input type='image' src='Delete.png'/>
                <input type='hidden' name='id' value='${nextMovie.id}'/>    
           </form>

         </c:forEach>
```

This is my controller:

```
          @RequestMapping("/removeFromCart")
public ModelAndView removeFromCart(HttpSession session) {


    ShoppingCart cart = (ShoppingCart) session.getAttribute("cart");
    if (cart == null) {
        cart = new ShoppingCart();
    }
    List<Movie> allMovies = cart.getAllItems();

      for(int i= 0;i<allMovies.size();i++)
      {
          allMovies.remove(i);
      }

    return new ModelAndView("/cartContents.jsp", "cart", allMovies);
}
```

Please suggest me how I will be able to delete the element again the delete button from the list.

Thanks
Maruthi

Comment: Please edit your question to reflect the code changes you have referred to in the comments below.

Answer (score 1):

```
[HttpPost]


[Route("~/CartDetail/DeleteCartDetail")]


public ActionResult DeleteCartDetail(CartDetailModel model)                                 

{
    var response = _cartDetailService.DeleteCartItem(model.Id);
    return Json(new  
    {
        success = response.Success,
        message = response.Message
        });
    }
}
```

I am importing my data from service **DeleteCartItem**

Here is service code

public BaseResponse DeleteCartItem(int cartDetailId)

```
{
    var response = new BaseResponse();

    try

    {
        var itemCart = _context.CartDetails.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Id == cartDetailId);

        if (itemCart == null)
        {
            response.Message = "This item does not exist in the cart.";
            return response;
        }
        _context.CartDetails.Remove(itemCart);
        _context.SaveChanges();
        response.Success = true;
    }
    catch (Exception exception)
    {
        response.Message = "Some error occured : " + exception.ToString();
    }
    return response;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your JSP has nested `<c:forEach>` tags, with both containing the same `items` expression. Either you don't need 2 of them of else you need to close the first one before starting the second.

Comment: Ok..I have removed the repeated tags:<c:set var="totalPrice" value="${0}" />
           <c:forEach var="nextMovie" items="${cart}">
   <li>
    <h2>${nextMovie.title}</h2>
               </li>
   <h2>Price</h2>
   <h2>${nextMovie.price}</h2>
      <c:set var="totalPrice" value="${totalPrice + nextMovie.price}"/>
         <input type='image' src='Delete.png'/>
                   <input type='hidden' name='id' value='${nextMovie.id}'/> 
           </c:forEach> .

Comment: assume my page displays :  movieName1 price "deleteButton" movieName2 Price "deleteButton" .Now I want remove movieName2 from the cart ,so I click the deleteButton against it.I want the movieName2 to removed from the list,so that cart would display only movieName1.Can you please suggest something like that.

Answer (score 0):

Your application has some problems:

First, your problem is because you are using the same `var` attribute name, for your both `foreach` tags. The first tag defines an attribute named `nextMovie` in its scope, the second `foreach` which is nested within first, defines the same attribute name, and then iterates, so when its iteration completes, `nextMovie` will be last element in the list, so `${nextMovie.id}` will be last element's id.

Second,

```
List<Movie> allMovies = cart.getAllItems();

for (int i= 0;i<allMovies.size();i++) {
    allMovies.remove(i);
}
```

is equivalent of `allMovies.clear()`, isn't it? So you are removing all items form list, what else do you need?

Third, next problem is you have an object of type `ShoppingCart` in your session which is named `cart`, and you add an object of type `List<Movie>` to your model with the same name; although when EL processor tries to resolve a name request has a more priority than session, but believe me it is much better to rename one.

Forth,  why are you calculating 'totalPrice' in each iteration? And what is its use?

Comment: Hi , the delete logic is incorrect.it would clear all.thats what is my problem now and I want to delete the marked against the delete .please donot consider my code.please suggest I have to proceed.thAnks